# VirtualBox module using dkms fails because there are no headers for latest kernel

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, dpkg, compiling

I just upgraded to the 4.12.0-041200.-generic kernel due to firefox issues with 4.10. I'm running 17.04.

I did this:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-26 linux-headers-4.10.0-26-generic linux-image-4.10.0-26-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-26-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-26-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/641 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 350604 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_5.1.22-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.04.1_all.deb ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.1.22
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.1.22-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.04.1) over (5.1.22-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.04.1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.1.22-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.04.1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.1.22 DKMS files...
Building for 4.12.0-041200-generic
Building initial module for 4.12.0-041200-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.12.0-041200-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.12.0-041200-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/make.log for more information.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-07-29 11:04:34 PDT; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16149 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers virtualbox[16149]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers virtualbox[16149]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers virtualbox[16149]:    ...fail!
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 29 11:04:34 dabbers systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
$more make.log
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-5.1.22 for kernel 4.12.0-041200-generic (x86_64)
Sat Jul 29 11:04:30 PDT 2017
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.12.0-041200-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:31:0:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘VBoxHost_RTMemContAlloc’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:323:47: error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_pages_x’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declar
ation]
 # define MY_SET_PAGES_EXEC(pPages, cPages)    set_pages_x(pPages, cPages)
                                               ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:445:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_SET_PAGES_EXEC’
             MY_SET_PAGES_EXEC(&paPages[iPage], 1);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘VBoxHost_RTMemContFree’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:324:47: error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_pages_nx’ [-Werror=implicit-function-decla
ration]
 # define MY_SET_PAGES_NOEXEC(pPages, cPages)  set_pages_nx(pPages, cPages)
                                               ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:493:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_SET_PAGES_NOEXEC’
             MY_SET_PAGES_NOEXEC(&paPages[iPage], 1);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:302: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjLinuxVirtToPage’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:922:27: error: passing argument 1 of ‘pud_offset’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=inc
ompatible-pointer-types]
     u.Upper = *pud_offset(&u.Global, ulAddr);
                           ^
In file included from ./include/linux/mm.h:70:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:98,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h:826:22: note: expected ‘p4d_t * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ but argument is of type ‘pgd_t * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
 static inline pud_t *pud_offset(p4d_t *p4d, unsigned long address)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:302: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:561: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
Makefile:1512: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.22/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.12.0-041200-generic'
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do - what's your goal at this point? To me it's not clear from your question. You need to use this kernel, but since APT can't get headers for it, dkms can't build a module for VB, is that right?

Comment: dkms doesn't support 4.12 kernel yet. It's an unsupported configuration at this time.

Comment: yes and how do I fix it, so it can build the module.

Comment: Again... this is unsupported... but you might see if dkms from 17.10 can be installed on your 17.04... no guarantees that it won't wreck your system. What Firefox issues are you trying to fix?

Comment: Freezing constantly, Yeah I suppose I can upgrade it to 17.10 and see what happens.  Thanks for the support.

Comment: @AndrewCayce I wouldn't recommend 17.10 yet. Freezing in Firefox is usually a bad extension. Does it freeze if you disable all optional extensions? Is Firefox the only problem that you have with this system? Show me `ls -alt /var/crash`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about memory driving. I hope this [patch](https://gist.github.com/herbmillerjr/a48314d18d65a60ee22c40790aaafc0b#file-virtualbox-modules-5-1-22-page-table-patch) for virtualbox will help you.

Comment: Instructions on how to use that patch may be helpful.